# Why is this dropdown link color different?

Tags: css, debugging, drop-down-menu, firebug

I hate css, this makes no sense.  I finally finished styling this menu and now I click a different page and the links are all white on a white dropdown bg.  I can only think it somehow has to do with the li.current-menu-item style but it doesn't make sense why.  Nothing shows up in firebug either.

This page works correctly: http://www.brainbuzzmedia.com/themes/simplybusiness/

This one has white links: http://www.brainbuzzmedia.com/themes/simplybusiness/?page_id=86

If you figure this out could you please tell me how or what you use to debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the second link, the sub–menu item links are having the white colour applied with the following CSS:

```
div.nav-menu ul li.current-menu-item:hover a
```

What you should change this to is:

```
div.nav-menu ul li.current-menu-item:hover > a
```

As you only want to target the children `<a>`s of `<li class="current-menu-item">`, not all descendants.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators

Answer (score 1):

The portfolio page (and subsequently any page you navigate to..) has an additional selector style "current-menu-item".  Either get rid of it or style appropriately

```
div.nav-menu ul li.current-menu-item a {
    color: #EE8855;
}
```

Comment: I know this.  I did this.  This is not white.